# AttributeError: 'Event' object has no attribute 'key' I cant find the error

Tags: python, pygame

Im creating a simple game, but after all the code, i get two error msgs:  File "C:/Users/victo/PycharmProjects/SnakeGame/Snake_Game.py", line 96, in 
snakegame()

and

File "C:/Users/victo/PycharmProjects/SnakeGame/Snake_Game.py", line 60, in snakegame
elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
AttributeError: 'Event' object has no attribute 'key'

I dont know what the fault is?
Here is the code:

```
import pygame
import time
import random

pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 60

redcolor = (213, 50, 80)
greencolor = (0, 255, 0)
blackcolor = (0, 0, 0)
whitecolor = (255, 255, 255)

width, height = 640, 800
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Snake Game')

snake_block = 18
snake_speed = 15
snake_list = [1]
def snake(snake_block, snake_list):
    for x in snake_list:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, greencolor, [x[50], x[50], snake_block, snake_block])

def snakegame():
    game_over = False
    game_end = False
    x1 = width / 2
    y1 = height / 2

    x1_change = 0
    y1_change = 0

    snake_list[0]
    Length_of_snake = 1

    foodx = round(random.randrange(0, width - snake_block) / 10.0) * 10.0
    foody = round(random.randrange(0, height - snake_block) / 10.0) * 10.0


    while not game_over:
        while game_end == True:
            score = Length_of_snake - 1
            score_font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsanms", 35)
            value = score_font.render("Your Score: " + str(score), True, whitecolor)
            screen.blit(value, [width / 3, height / 5])
            pygame.display.update()
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    game_over = True
                    game_end = False

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                game_over = True
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                     x1_change = -snake_block
                     y1_change = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                     x1_change = snake_block
                     y1_change = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                     x1_change = 0
                     y1_change = -snake_block
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                     x1_change = 0
                     y1_change = snake_block
        if x1 >= width or x1 < 0 or y1 >= height or y1 <0:
            game_end = True
        x1 += x1_change
        y1 += y1_change
        screen.fill(blackcolor)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, redcolor, [foodx, foody, snake_block, snake_block])
        snake_Head = []
        snake_Head.append(x1)
        snake_Head.append(y1)
        snake_list.append(snake_Head)

        if len(snake_list) > Length_of_snake:
            del snake_list[0]

        for x in snake_list[:-1]:
            if  x == snake_Head:
                game_end = True
        snake(snake_block, snake_list)
        pygame.display.update()

        if x1 == foodx and y1 == foody:
            foodx = round(random.randrange(0, width - snake_block) / 10.0) * 10.0
            foody = round(random.randrange(0, height - snake_block) / 10.0) * 10.0
            Length_of_snake += 1
        clock.tick(snake_speed)
    pygame.quit()
    quit()
snakegame()
```

Comment: You just need to indent all the `elif` with one more tab

Comment: When i did that it gave me even more error and still didnt work =(

Comment: You get the second error because you are trying to access 49th element in the "snake_list" when it only contains 1 item, in the function "snake"

Answer (score 0):

try this

you should also try using a square grid, because your grid system is confusing

```
import pygame
import time
import random

pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 60

redcolor = (213, 50, 80)
greencolor = (0, 255, 0)
blackcolor = (0, 0, 0)
whitecolor = (255, 255, 255)

width, height = 640, 800
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Snake Game')

snake_block = 18
snake_speed = 15
snake_list = [1]
def snake(snake_block, snake_list):
    for x in snake_list:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, greencolor, [x[0], x[1], snake_block, snake_block])

def snakegame():
    game_over = False
    game_end = False
    x1 = width / 2
    y1 = height / 2

    x1_change = 0
    y1_change = 0

    snake_list[0]
    Length_of_snake = 1

    foodx = round(random.randrange(0, width - snake_block) / 10.0) * 10.0
    foody = round(random.randrange(0, height - snake_block) / 10.0) * 10.0


    while not game_over:
        while game_end == True:
            score = Length_of_snake - 1
            score_font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsanms", 35)
            value = score_font.render("Your Score: " + str(score), True, whitecolor)
            screen.blit(value, [width / 3, height / 5])
            pygame.display.update()
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    game_over = True
                    game_end = False

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                game_over = True
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    x1_change = -snake_block
                    y1_change = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x1_change = snake_block
                    y1_change = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    x1_change = 0
                    y1_change = -snake_block
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    x1_change = 0
                    y1_change = snake_block
        if x1 >= width or x1 < 0 or y1 >= height or y1 <0:
            game_end = True
        x1 += x1_change
        y1 += y1_change
        screen.fill(blackcolor)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, redcolor, [foodx, foody, snake_block, snake_block])
        snake_Head = []
        snake_Head.append(x1)
        snake_Head.append(y1)
        snake_list.append(snake_Head)

        if len(snake_list) > Length_of_snake:
            del snake_list[0]

        for x in snake_list[:-1]:
            if  x == snake_Head:
                game_end = True
        snake(snake_block, snake_list)
        pygame.display.update()

        if x1 == foodx and y1 == foody:
            foodx = round(random.randrange(0, width - snake_block) / 10.0) * 10.0
            foody = round(random.randrange(0, height - snake_block) / 10.0) * 10.0
            Length_of_snake += 1
        clock.tick(snake_speed)
    pygame.quit()
    quit()
snakegame()
```